# Proof with natural deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

$(p\rightarrow \bot)\rightarrow \bot \vdash p$

I need to prove this using natural deduction.

I tried assuming that $\neg p$ is true, so I can prove $p$ by contradiction. I do not have   $\neg p$ defined as $p\rightarrow \bot$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: i assumed that ~p is true, so i can prove p by contradiction

Comment: What set of rules are you using ? Is $\lnot p$ defined as $p \to \bot$ ?

Comment: no it is not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the set of rules of Michael Huth & Mark Ryan, [Logic in Computer Science : Modelling and Reasoning about Systems (Cambridge UP, 2004)](https://books.google.it/books?id=eUggAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), page 27.

1) $(p→⊥)→⊥$ --- premise

$\quad$2) $\lnot p$ --- assumed [a]

$\qquad$3) $p$ --- assumed [b]

$\qquad$4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\lnot$-elim

$\quad$5) $p \to \bot$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b]

$\quad$6) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 5) by $\to$-elim

7) $p$ --- from 2) and 6) by $\lnot \lnot$-elim, discharging [a].

Comment: Thank you :) :)